# How to change month automatically in an entire column without changing respective days?

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I´m doing a macro in Google spreadshets and I need a command to advance one month keeping the same day of the month. The format doesn't matter.
For instance, in the first column I have all the days of March 2019, and with the command I need what is shown in the second column, by converting each day to the same day of April. And then with the same command pass from April to May (third column). And so on.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in B1 cell and drag to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A:$A<>"", 
 DATE(YEAR($A:$A), MONTH($A:$A)+COLUMN(A1), DAY($A:$A)), ))
```

[image: 0]